# Problems with rationalizing an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am faced with this problem:

> Express $R$ as a rational expression: $\frac1{R} = \frac1{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac1{R_3}$

If I'm correct, rationalizing an expression means simplifying it. I cant figure out how to do this. If anyone can help me that would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Equivalent resistance of 3 resistors in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *rational expression* is of the form $a/b$ for polynomials $a$ and $b$.

\begin{align}
R&=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{R_2R_3+R_1R_3+R_1R_2}{R_1R_2R_3}}\\
&=\frac{R_1R_2R_3}{R_2R_3+R_1R_3+R_1R_2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

in this sense, *rational* means *of or pertaining to a ratio*. This could refer to a ratio of polynomials or integers, but generally not *Real numbers* (as *Irrational numbers* are not considered *Rational* [by definition])